# How to prevent angular webpack from editing in browser side?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a angular application which compiles & creates dist folder. In browser console, I'am able to edit the webpack. Because of that I can edit the response which is coming from server & Iam able to breach in to next page.

After running the angular application using ng build, It creates a dist folder. After that we are running the node server. We also get response from node server like "login sucess". We are comparing that response in angular ui side & routing to other page. Here if we see the browser console, We are able to edit the server response from browser side ( We are able to edit the webpack file) & we are able to breach in to next page. How can I prevent editing the webpack from browser side?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? Can you give an example of the steps you take?

Comment: @bracco23 After running the angular application using ng build, It creates a dist folder. After that we are running the node server. We also get response from node server like "login sucess". We are comparing that response in angular ui side & routing to other page. Here if we see the browser console, We are able to edit the server response from browser side ( We are able to edit the webpack file) & we are able to breach in to next page.. could you help me with this? How can I prevent editing the webpack from browser side..

Comment: you cannot? you can make it really really difficult by uglifying the compiled output, but with web apps a smart user will always be able to tamper with the data. that's why security-relevant logic should be only server-side, with the browser carrying the relevant information across requests. @sasi

Comment: @bracco23 Actually the logic part is there in server side only, we are just sending true or false kind of reponse just for the navigation purpose. IS there a way to prevent editing the webpack?

Comment: If it is just for navigational purposes, can you elaborate why this is a concern? At the end of the day, the UI has to run on the user's machine and thus they will _always_ be able to edit the code/values at run-time